# Custom xml validation inside eclipse plugin with Custom Validator?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to validate a custom content type document(xml kind), with an custom validator. Want to validate it with a xsd, but only after certain preprocessing of main document.
Normal xml validator can't be used because-
1.) The schema location(xsd) & namespaces are not defined in the main document file.
2.) And bcz of first reason & many more, want to do some preprocessing to the document file, before applying xsd validation.

So I want to use the xml validator, but only after preprocessing of my file.

My plugin.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

<extension
point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.contentTypes">

<content-type
id="com.xyz.ide.core.contentType.dummy"
base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
file-extensions="blabla"
/>

</extension>

<extension
point="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation">
<validator
scope="total"
class="mc.CustomValidator"
id="com.xyz.myValidator">
<contentTypeIdentifier
id="com.xyz.ide.core.contentType.dummy">
<partitionType
id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.XML_DEFAULT">
</partitionType>
</contentTypeIdentifier>
</validator>
</extension>

</plugin>
```

CustomValidator.java

```
public class CustomValidator implements ISourceValidator, IValidator {
XMLValidator validator = new XMLValidator();
IDocument document;

public void validate(IValidationContext helper, IReporter reporter) {
String fileContent = this.document.get();
final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.toLowerCase().getBytes());

// Whats the problem in this line???
XMLValidationReport report = validator.validate("/home/rchawla/xmlWorkspace/abc.xsd", is);

ValidationMessage[] messages = report.getValidationMessages();
for(ValidationMessage message:messages){
System.out.println(message.getMessage());
}
}
```

I can hit the validate method on running the plugin in debug mode, but
the document is not getting validated with the xsd.
What is wrong in the above method as,
ValidationMessage[] messages = report.getValidationMessages(); is giving zero messages, even though the there are errors in the main document file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a lot of trouble trying to make `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.sourcevalidation` extension point work. I ended up using another extension point [org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.validation.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/vf/org_eclipse_wst_validation_validatorV2.html). The only difference between the 2 validators is that this one is only triggered when you save a file, not while you are typing. See an example bellow :

```
<extension id="customValidator" name="Custom Validator" point="org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2">
    <validator class="aaa.bbb.CustomValidator" markerId="customMarker" version="3">
        <include>
            <rules>
                <contentType id="customContentType" exactMatch="false"/>
            </rules>
        </include>
    </validator>
</extension>
```

Your implementation of the validator should override `org.eclipse.wst.validation.AbstractValidator`.